# Unwanted parallel lines in world map by ggmap in R

Tags: r, ggmap

I am plotting a world map using ggmap. My code is below:

```
library(maps)
library(ggmap)
library(repr)
library(ggthemes)
library(ggplot2)
options(repr.plot.width=16, repr.plot.height=8)



world_map<-map_data("world")

world_map<-world_map[order(world_map$order),]
ggplot(world_map,aes(x=long,y=lat))+
     geom_polygon(aes(group = group, fill = "red"),color='white')+
       coord_map("mercator")+
            theme_map()
```

I am getting unwanted lines (cutting across Russia).

[image]

@mrhellmann thanks; it had solved the issue; (I cannot reply for some reason)

Comment: Did the answer blow fix your problem, Anshu?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `sf` package to transform the data you have from ggplot2.

Transform the dataframe to an `sf` object, then plot it using `geom_sf`.

```r
library(dplyr)

library(ggplot2)
library(sf)

world_map <- map_data('world')

world_sf <- world_map %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c('long', 'lat'), crs = 4326) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise(geometry = st_combine(geometry)) %>% 
  st_cast('POLYGON')

ggplot(world_sf) +
  geom_sf(fill = 'red')
```

[image]

Or, use the `rnaturalearth` package to get a clean `sf` object to work with:

```
library(rnaturalearth)

ne_world <- ne_countries(returnclass = 'sf')

ggplot(ne_world) +
  geom_sf(fill = 'red') +
  theme_void()
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2020-12-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>